Spring не видит mysql при запуске docker-compose
The application starts without errors, but when I go to the site to check, all requests to the database do not give a response as if it is not connected.
Dockerfile:
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache mysql-client
WORKDIR /dayzwiki
COPY /target/dayz-wiki-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /dayzwiki/dayzwiki.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "dayzwiki.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080


application-docker.properties:
MYSQl
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db:3307/dayz_wiki
spring.datasource.username=bestuser
spring.datasource.password=0000
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

docker-compose.yml:
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "3307:3307"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dayz_wiki
      MYSQL_USER: bestuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 0000
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 0000
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3307
    command: --port=3307
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 --silent"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  app:
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: java-container
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3307/dayz_wiki
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: bestuser
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: 0000
volumes:
  db_data:

LOGS:
PS D:\DayZ-Wiki> docker-compose up --build
[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ db Pulled                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1.4s 
[+] Building 3.1s (11/11) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                                  docker:desktop-linux
 => [app internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 253B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s 
 => [app internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine                                                                                                                                                                                1.4s 
 => [app auth] library/eclipse-temurin:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [app internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s 
 => [app 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine@sha256:4708e1a2c3baa0855eb9b3e6ae6285c8640d574c25ba74fddf6b8a17ccc3673f                                                                                                                          0.1s 
 => => resolve docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine@sha256:4708e1a2c3baa0855eb9b3e6ae6285c8640d574c25ba74fddf6b8a17ccc3673f                                                                                                                              0.1s 
 => [app internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 85B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
 => CACHED [app 2/4] RUN apk add --no-cache mysql-client                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [app 3/4] WORKDIR /dayzwiki                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => CACHED [app 4/4] COPY /target/dayz-wiki-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /dayzwiki/dayzwiki.jar                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => [app] exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        1.3s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => => exporting manifest sha256:c4f66e38a382c90d526a4f84ecab8316c0ced0927fd5eaf7952a3bc0bb1e1b53                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => => exporting config sha256:214304ae1b9391be9413994370396d5930da0fbd400e3c754fe0847139b7a993                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s 
 => => exporting attestation manifest sha256:068c5cf2b219aa23e6e583ea74d1a027832674703596229dc95df66bfa98f3e6                                                                                                                                                       0.1s 
 => => exporting manifest list sha256:56e34bea99397df46b18eb37a8d06bd4729d65b2a37b74f731473e9a687c74e6                                                                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/dayz-wiki-app:latest                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => => unpacking to docker.io/library/dayz-wiki-app:latest                                                                                                                                                                                                          1.1s 
 => [app] resolving provenance for metadata file                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
[+] Running 4/4
 ✔ Network dayz-wiki_default   Created                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.1s 
 ✔ Volume "dayz-wiki_db_data"  Created                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s 
 ✔ Container db                Created                                                                                                                                                                                                                              3.9s 
 ✔ Container java-container    Created                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.2s 
Attaching to db, java-container
db              | 2024-12-08 22:13:59+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.40-1.el9 started.
db              | 2024-12-08 22:13:59+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db              | 2024-12-08 22:13:59+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.40-1.el9 started.
db              | 2024-12-08 22:13:59+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
db              | 2024-12-08T22:13:59.706542Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
db              | 2024-12-08T22:13:59.706629Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.40) initializing of server in progress as process 81
db              | 2024-12-08T22:13:59.715220Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:00.558965Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:02.339328Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
db              | 2024-12-08 22:14:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
db              | 2024-12-08 22:14:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:08.476904Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:08.477936Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.40) starting as process 125
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:08.491809Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:08.946020Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:09.338457Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:09.338505Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:09.351821Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:09.382540Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:09.382657Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.40'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
db              | 2024-12-08 22:14:09+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
db              | '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
db              | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db              | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
db              | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leapseconds' as time zone. Skipping it.
db              | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/tzdata.zi' as time zone. Skipping it.
db              | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db              | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db              | 2024-12-08 22:14:11+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database dayz_wiki
db              | 2024-12-08 22:14:11+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user bestuser
db              | 2024-12-08 22:14:11+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user bestuser access to schema dayz_wiki
db              | 
db              | 2024-12-08 22:14:11+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:11.830862Z 13 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.40).
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:14.279776Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.40)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
db              | 2024-12-08 22:14:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped
db              |
db              | 2024-12-08 22:14:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
db              |
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:15.034923Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:15.036371Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.40) starting as process 1
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:15.044724Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:15.585171Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:16.059497Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:16.059565Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:16.069027Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:16.105519Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
db              | 2024-12-08T22:14:16.105611Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.40'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3307  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
java-container  | SLF4J(W): Class path contains multiple SLF4J providers.
java-container  | SLF4J(W): Found provider [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider@69d9c55]
java-container  | SLF4J(W): Found provider [org.slf4j.simple.SimpleServiceProvider@13a57a3b]
java-container  | SLF4J(W): See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
java-container  | SLF4J(I): Actual provider is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider@69d9c55]
java-container  | 
java-container  |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
java-container  |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
java-container  | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
java-container  |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
java-container  |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
java-container  |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
java-container  |  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.5)
java-container  |
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:21.387Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] c.dayzwiki.portal.DayzWikiApplication    : Starting DayzWikiApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.13 with PID 1 (/dayzwiki/dayzwiki.jar started by root in /dayzwiki)
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:21.390Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] c.dayzwiki.portal.DayzWikiApplication    : The following 1 profile is active: "local"
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:22.430Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:22.579Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 139 ms. Found 18 JPA repository interfaces.
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:23.338Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:23.352Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:23.352Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.20]
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:23.402Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:23.403Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1906 ms
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:23.580Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:23.645Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.4.Final
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:23.692Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:23.953Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:23.993Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:24.310Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@44aeae34
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:24.312Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:25.591Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:30.067Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:30.748Z  WARN 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:31.210Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@62a78446, org.springframework.security.web.c
ontext.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5a919251, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@2da3d7d3, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2b33e616, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logou
t.LogoutFilter@42af2977, com.dayzwiki.portal.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter@40612056, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@47184859, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@22781286, org
.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@33a0b857, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5f7dbdfa, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@175c4ae5, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@5d6cac57]
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:31.952Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
java-container  | 2024-12-08T22:14:31.975Z  INFO 1 --- [DayZWiki] [           main] c.dayzwiki.portal.DayzWikiApplication    : Started DayzWikiApplication in 11.106 seconds (process running for 11.659)

Что я пробовал:

Change MySQL port (3306 is busy)
Connect to database bestuser and root, in console wrote:

C:\Windows\system32>docker exec -it db sh
sh-5.1# mysql -u bestuser -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bestuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)


Please re-publish your question in Russian.

Вы написали в docker-compose.yml
MYSQL_PASSWORD: 0000

Литерал 0000 YAML интерпретирует как число 0, поэтому пароль у вас 0
Проверьте:
docker exec -it db sh
sh-5.1# set | grep MYSQL
MYSQL_DATABASE=dayz_wiki
MYSQL_MAJOR=8.0
MYSQL_PASSWORD=0
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=0
MYSQL_SHELL_VERSION=8.0.40-1.el9
MYSQL_TCP_PORT=3307
MYSQL_USER=bestuser
MYSQL_VERSION=8.0.40-1.el9

Если логиниться в mysql с паролем 0, то всё получается.
sh-5.1# mysql -u bestuser -p dayz_wiki 
Enter password: 0<ввод>
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 73
Server version: 8.0.40 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2024, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

Если вы хотите, чтобы пароль был 0000,то в YAML нужно написать строковый литерал '0000'

Спасибо за ответ, очень помог, я целую ночь не мог понять в чём проблема
